# How do I extract cvv from the discretionary numbers on a track 2 dump

Tags: javascript, python

How do I extract a cvv from the discretionary numbers on a track 2 dump
I got everything before the = sign and I got the first 7 numbers after the = sign but the discretionary numbers they are called fall after the service code and I've been told that the  PIN and CVV numbers are in the discretionary portion of the numbers

Comment: Oops! Looks like you forgot to post the code you're having trouble with. [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)